# Which set are these 3 LEGO bags from?

Tags: set-identification

[image]

I've got 3 bags.

- On the bag 1 it says 529r9
- Bags 2 and 3 says 629r9

Is there any way to figure out what set are these bags from?

Comment: Those codes only indicate when the bags were filled (5th and 6th day of week 29 of 2019 respectively) and give no information about the set itself. Can you attach a picture of the bags so we can identify the set by the pieces in the bags? Thanks!

Comment: Just added! Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

It's Harry Potter set [75947](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75947-1) (Buckbeak's rescue).

[image: BrickLink image]

Comment: How did you find out?

Comment: @til_b The wings  might have helped.

Comment: I actually looked for the umbrella first, as there are a LOT of pieces named *wing* and I wasn't at all confident I would get the right one. But one of the few sets with a pinkish umbrella was a Buckbeak set, so I looked at the inventory, and it had big wings that looked the same. And it turns out that is the only set that has that particular type of wing in that color. As the cellists say, viola!

Comment: Maybe I'm not remembering the movie very well, but it's odd that the guy with the axe looks like Darth Vader...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: The resemblance wasn't striking in the movie https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Executioner?file=Walden_macnair.jpeg

Comment: @EricDuminil Indeed, I'm just wondering if the people who designed this set just used a Darth Vader helmet instead of creating a new piece because it's "close enough"?